# Display last result from multiple tables in Django

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I'm trying to display the latest result out of multiple tables in Django. So basically I will end up with lots of Divs on my page each with the value and time of the latest entry into each table.

The code below is just some basic thoughts that I have put together but doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is use a for loop to go around for each table and add the latest table entry to the variable item. That then gets sent to the HTML which does another for loop to make all the Divs with the data.

Does Django have a simpler way of doing this?

Many thanks!

view.py

```
for table in tables:
        itemName = getattr(models, 'Item{0}'.format(table))
        item = itemName.objects.all()[:1]

    return render(request, 'html/list_view.html',
        {'item': item})
```

HTML

```
{% for item in item %}

<div>
    <h1>{{ table name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ item.time }}</p>  
    <p>{{ item.value }}</p> 
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing - can you clarify what you are trying to do a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase the performance is to save only the latest item of all the tables in a single table and differentiate them by adding a field like `itemType`. So you have to just query this table and for loop it in the template.

If your item tables are very different and have different fields, then saving in single table would not be feasible. In this case I think what you are doing is fine. I would only change the query to get the last entry like:

```
item = itemName.objects.last()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very interesting actually and might be the answer as the tables all have exactly the same fields.